# How to set custom sound for GCM Push notification in cordova mobile app

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using ionic with cordova framework, i have created push notification for my application it's working well.
I used below plugin for push notification

> https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git

Whenever i receive the notification it produce 3times repeating sound from default notification sound. How to set single sound or how to set custom sound for my notification.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you want to update? That version is deprecated, and in the new one, you can do it easily

new version: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

And the documentation for adding custom sounds:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#sound